# Manage position of a moving object

Tags: ios, object, random

I'm making my first iOS app, but I have a problem... Moving objects come from the top of the screen to the bottom.
The goal of the game is to kill moving objects (which have a random position.y) before they come out of the screen.
If the object come out, you lose one of your 3 lives.
I do it like that:

```
if(movingObject.position.y < 0)
    _lives--;
```

But when I launch my app, and an object come out of the screen, I lose immediately my 3 lives...

What could I do to lose maximum 1 life by moving object?

Here is my code to create a new movingObject

```
double curTime = CACurrentMediaTime();
if (curTime > _nextMovingObjectSpawn)
{
    float randSecs = [self randomValueBetween:3 andValue:5];
    _nextMovingObjectSpawn = randSecs + curTime;

    float randX = [self randomValueBetween:25 andValue:winSize.width/2-20];
    float randDuration = [self randomValueBetween:4 andValue:6];

    CCSprite *movingObject = [_movingObjects objectAtIndex:_nextMovingObject];
    _nextMovingObject++;
    if (_nextMovingObject >= _movingObjects.count) _nextMovingObject = 0;

    [movingObject stopAllActions];
    movingObject.position = ccp(randX, winSize.height+movingObject.contentSize.height/2);
    movingObject.visible = YES;
    [movingObject runAction:[CCSequence actions: [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:randDuration position:ccp(0, -winSize.height-movingObject.contentSize.height)], [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(setInvisible:)], nil]];
}
```

Thank you! :)

Comment: Not "in Xcode". Xcode is an IDE, it doesn't make random object - your code does.

Comment: Yes, I know, that's what I mean.

Comment: How often do you check the movingObject? Do you you destroy it(or set it to nill)? Do you use an Loop or a Timer?

Comment: What is the data type of your moving object ? a UIImageView ?

Comment: I check the movingObject all the time, and that's the problem... Then, I set the movingObject to visible = NO; and just 5 movingObject are visible. I don't use any loop or timer

Comment: Even though it is invisible, it still exists. You should probably remove it from its superview if it's a UIView subclass.

Comment: I'm using Cocos2D, do you know how I could delete an object? :/ Sorry if my question is stupid, I'm totally exhausted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your objects move from top to bottom then the player should lose a life when one of them reaches the bottom of the screen. You probably lose all the lives because you check the condition many times. To lose only one life per object, you should probably remove it and stop checking if its position is below the lower edge of the screen.

Comment: That's true, but the objects may start outside of the screen bounds.

Comment: I think from the current knowledge this is now the best answer ;)

Comment: Yes that's true, but how could I lose just 1 life by 1 moving object?

Comment: The first time the condition is true, you update the number of lives and remove the object.

Comment: Still doesn't work if I do that:

    `if(movingObject.position.y < 0)
    {
        _lives--;             
       [self removeChild:movingObject cleanup:YES];
    }`

Comment: You can fx try setting the object to nil: movingObject = nil or assigning a newly spawned object to the movingObject variable (so that a new object starts moving from the top of the screen)

Comment: The first method unfortunately doesn't work neither. How can I realize the second, I don't understand it very well... (Thank you helping me!)

Comment: It would help if you posted a little more of your code fx how you create moving objects.